# Does Sven's ult stack with double damage?

Tags: dota-2

Does Sven's ult stack with double damage? If it does, does the order of activating ult and double damage make any difference?

Answer (score 5):

Sven's ultimate gives you 100%/150%/200% bonus damage.

> Only increases base damage and that given by the primary attribute of Sven. Raw bonus damage is not increased.
>   – [Sven - Dota 2 Wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Sven)

Your damage consists of 2 numbers: `A +B`, and this description basically means that the ultimate gives you 100%/150%/200% of the `A` number. It excludes raw damage items (but items that give Strength still count)

Exactly the same can be said about the Double Damage rune: it gives you 100% of `A`.

Since both of these only increase `B` and are based only on `A`, their bonuses will not be multiplied with each other; they're completely independent. But they do stack in a sense. The order of activating them does not make a difference, and it probably wouldn't make a difference even if they stacked in some complicated way.

So if you have both Double Damage and Sven's ultimate level 3 active, your total damage will be:
`A+B + A*2 + A` (the `2` stands for 200%).